# fopen file name with UTF8 string in windows

Tags: c++, file, winapi, opencv, utf-8

When I used opencv's API `cvLoadImage(const char *filename, int iscolor)` It accepts `const char *` as file name. When the file name is not ASCII-character, I tried to convert it to UTF8 string. It fails because `fopen()` called in `cvLoadImage()` can not interpret the characters of the file name literally as ASCII string. I may used `_wfopen()` if tried to open file names, but if `fopen()` is called in the third-party library, is there any  method to handle this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't work, but code pages do. I assume that won't hack it? GetShortPathName is obviously the answer then.

Comment: Tell the third-party library to write to a file with an 8-bit name at a known location, such as a temp folder, then copy the file to whatever path you want.  Or, if reading, copy the file with an 8-bit name at a known location first.

Answer (score 9):

Use [GetShortPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It will return an old (8.3) name for the file, which you should be able to convert to `char*`, as it should not contain any non ASCII characters.

I've just tested it with some language specific characters and it worked as I described. I've successfully opened a file from `C:\łęłęł\ąóąóą.tsttgbb` using fopen.

Comment: That's an old-school trick... Will it work no matter what? If the folder has too many files?

Comment: @zmbq, you would need to have (10 + 52) ^ 7 (that's a power of 7) files to cause problems. I don't know if you're allowed to do that. So yeah, it should work. Someone correct me, if I'm wrong. Old school trick for old school libraries :).

Comment: Sorry, that should be 10 + 26, since it's not case sensitive

Comment: Yes, we've used that for when the filename is too long but never thought of using it for Unicode chars. Brilliant!

Comment: It is a common practice amongst administrators to disable the creation of short filenames on NTFS. Would your solution work in the case? Quoted from your link: _Resilient File System (ReFS) doesn't support short names. If you call GetShortPathName on a path that doesn't have any short names on-disk, the call will succeed, but will return the long-name path instead. This outcome is also possible with NTFS volumes because **there's no guarantee that a short name will exist for a given long name**_.

Answer (score 5):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, ".65001");

fopen(u8"中文路径.txt", "rb"); //window7(中文) vs2017 ok
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick search came up with nothing but people saying it can't be done. If you can't change `cvLoadImage` (which is reasonable, you don't want to mess with that), you can try to trick it.

1. You can create a link to the file, using the [`CreateSymbolicLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm not sure it'll work, though, because the `MKLINK` command line utility requires administrative privileges.
2. If you can't create a symbolic link, you can always copy the file to a different location with an ASCII-only name.
3. If you really don't want to copy the file and symlinks don't work, you can create a file-proxy - created a named pipe with an ASCII only name, and translate each read from the pipe to a read from the file.

I would go with options 1 or 2, though - a lot simpler.

Comment: Yes, My temp solution is I use MoveFile to temp.jpg, read it, then Move it back. It is just a trick.

Comment: @binzhang there are simpler ways, check my answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a late contribution to this problem.  I looked through the source of the runtime library (which Microsoft kindly supply) and found that I could replace the routine used by fopen to map an ANSI string with the following code (just link this into your exe and it will replace the routine in the runtime library).

The version listed works for Visual Studio 2017 using the v141_xp toolkit.  I haven't tested it for other versions but I imagine some minor changes (such as the name of the routine itself) might be needed.  It won't work of course if the offending library is a DLL.  Make of it what you will.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define _NORMAL_BLOCK   1
    #define _CRT_BLOCK      2
    #define _malloc_crt(s)  (_malloc_dbg  (s, _CRT_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__))
#else
    #define _malloc_crt     _malloc_base
#endif

// A hack to make fopen et al accept UTF8 strings (as at Visual Studio 2017), see:
//    D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\internal\string_utilities.cpp
//    D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal_traits.h
extern "C" BOOL __cdecl __acrt_copy_path_to_wide_string (char const* const path, wchar_t** const result)
{
    #if _MSC_VER != 1910
        #define STRINGIZE_HELPER(x) #x
        #define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_HELPER(x)
        __pragma (message (__FILE__ "(" STRINGIZE (__LINE__) ") : Error: Code not tested for this version of Visual Studio"));
    #endif

    assert (path);
    assert (result);

    // Compute the required size of the wide character buffer:
    int length = MultiByteToWideChar (CP_UTF8, 0, path, -1, nullptr, 0);
    assert (length > 0);

    *result = (wchar_t *) _malloc_crt (T2B (length));

    // Do the conversion:
    length = MultiByteToWideChar (CP_UTF8, 0, path, -1, *result, length);
    assert (length);
    return TRUE;
}
```